# How do you interact with the iPhone keyboard with no UITextView on the screen?

Tags: ios, keyboard, first-responder

We would like our app to display one of the built-in keyboards (specifically the numeric one) and be able to respond to key presses and such, but not via anything on the screen such as a `UITextView`.  We're actually just going to send those keystrokes out over the wire for something else and didn't feel like re-inventing the wheel with the keypad.  Think of it as us using the keypad as a matrix of UIButtons rather than us having to manually create our own, then worry about look and feel and such.

That said,

1. How can we show the keyboard with no `UITextView` or similar controls on the screen
2. How do we choose which one to show (again, we want the numeric one.)
3. How can we respond to KeyDown/KeyUp/KeyPress messages or what have you.

Answer (score 1):

You need a hidden UITextField with the appropriate [keyboard type](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/keyboardType) specified which you make first responder. You respond to keyboard entry by using the [text field delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html).

It would be an unusual UI to have no on-screen feedback to key presses, though.

Comment: There is feedback, but its in the form of graphics, not an editable text field. Rather than creating our own matrix of buttons, we're simply using the keyboard as if they were the buttons if you will.  And can you set something hidden as the first responder? Didn't think that was allowed. (I was leaning to an off-screen version for the same effect.) One last thing... out of curiosity, can you set the first responder via IB or do you have to do it via code? (We've always done the latter, but I always hated that.)

Comment: Don't see why hidden status should affect first responder. If so, you could put it off screen. First responder status is set through code, don't see how you would do it through IB as it could change during run time. There is initial first responder somewhere but I can't remember where off the top of my head (might even be an OS x thing, I'm away from my mac ATM)

Answer (score 0):

The safest place for a hidden UITextView is probably at CGRectMake(0,view.frame.size.height,whateverWidth,whateverHeight). Then when you addSubview: it will be off screen by definition. You may need to relocate the frame on didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation if you allow rotation, though - perhaps make both x and y to MAX(view.frame.size.height,view.frame.size.width), which will always be off screen.

Otherwise, if hidden is a problem you can use alpha .03 - this is pretty much invisible but still responds to user interaction. That's not an answer for this exact problem, but keep it in your back pocket for future reference.

Good luck,

Damien